# Dynamic routing angularJS on the basis of a JSON response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, routes, route-provider

With the function ContentService.getQuestions() i get a JSON with the property 'Type'. This property type can be 'DevOps' or something else.
If the Type property contains the string 'DevOps', I want to load a different template. And if its not 'Devops', I want to load a different template.

The code:

```
function configureRouting($routeProvider) {
    var tempUrl = '';

    $routeProvider
        .when('/form', {
            resolve: {
                dataService: function (ContentService) {
                    var questions = ContentService.getQuestions();
                    var resolved = Promise.resolve(questions);
                    resolved.then(function (q) {
                        console.log(q.Type);
                        if (q.Type === 'DevOps') {
                            tempUrl = 'components/devops/template.html';
                        } else {
                            tempUrl = 'components/hr/template.html';
                        }
                    });
                    return questions;
                }
            },
            controller: 'FormController',
            controllerAs: 'frmCtrl',
            templateUrl: tempUrl
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/form'
        });
}
```

In the code the tempUrl doest change, because the templateUrl: tempUrl takes the original variable, who isnt changed.
So I need a solution where I can load a different template on the basis of my JSON property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function for returning  template url like this ...

```
function configureRouting($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/form', {                    
                controller: 'FormController',
                controllerAs: 'frmCtrl',
                templateUrl: function(ContentService){
                     var tempUrl = '';
                     var questions = ContentService.getQuestions();
                        var resolved = Promise.resolve(questions);
                        resolved.then(function (q) {
                            console.log(q.Type);
                            if (q.Type === 'DevOps') {
                                tempUrl = 'components/devops/template.html';
                            } else {
                                tempUrl = 'components/hr/template.html';
                            }
                        });
                        return tempUrl;
                }

            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/form'
            });
    }
```

Comment: Then I am getting an TypeError: ContentService.getQuestions is not a function.